# what is the scope for ui-select2 ng-model

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

I am running in to a strange problem and unable to understand whats going on.

I an using the following code

```
<select ui-select2 class="span4" multiple 
    ng-model="WhseAssociations" 
    ng-change="valueChanged(WhseAssociations)"
    data-placeholder="Select associated warehouses" 
    ng-options="whse.WarehouseName for whse in allShipperWarehouses">
</select>
```

on the controller I have

```
$scope.WhseAssociations = new Array();

$scope.valueChanged = function(whse){
   alert(angular.toJson(whse));
}
```

the changes made to the selection is not reflected in the `WhseAssociations` variable of the `$scope` when i am referring it at a later time, however inside the `valueChanged(whse)` function the `whse` is fully populated but the `$scope.WhseAssociations` is not populated.

so the question I have is what is the scope of this `WhseAssociations` and how can I access this inside my controller?

Answer (score 0):

ui-select2 is incompatible with `<select ng-options>`, as per the project description at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2#working-with-dynamic-options

This should do it:

```
<select ui-select2 class="span4" multiple 
    ng-model="WhseAssociations" 
    ng-change="valueChanged(WhseAssociations)"
    data-placeholder="Select associated warehouses">
<option value=""></option>
<option ng-repeat="whse in allShipperWarehouses">{{whse.WarehouseName}}</option>
</select>
```